# How do I combine 3 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I need some help here

I have 3 tables which looked like:

```
user_base_info
+-------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|user_id| real_name |    live_province |   live_city      | live_area_big    | live_area_small  |
+-------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|    1  |  John     |      15000000    |    15300000      |    15310000      |    15310003      |
|    2  |  Susan    |      42000000    |    42140000      |    42140400      |    42140401      |
|    3  |  Andy     |      12000000    |    58300000      |    58302000      |    58302004      |
|    4  |  Knoxvile |      12000000    |    12100000      |    12110000      |    12110002      |
|    5  |  Abraham  |      13000000    |    50200000      |    50200000      |    11115007      |
|  ...  |  ........ |      ...         |    ...           |    ...           |    ...           |
|331508 |  Donald   |      41000000    |    41010000      |    41011200      |    41011202      |
+-------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+

borrow_progress
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+
|user_id | borrow_id |  state     |  remark    | create_time |
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+
|  170   |  236      |  10        |  waiting   |  24/04/17   |   
|  170   |  236      |  22        |  proceed   |  02/02/17   |     
|  170   |  236      |  26        |  success   |  25/04/17   |    
|  170   |  236      |  30        |  sent      |  05/11/17   |   
|  172   |  237      |  40        |  completed |  03/07/17   |   
|  ...   |  ...      |  ...       |  ...       |    ...      |   
| 353252 | 24112     |  90        |  failed    |  30/01/17   |   
+--------+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+

area
+------------+---------------------+
|code        |      name           |
+------------+---------------------+
| 11000000   | Jawa Tengah         |   
| 12000000   | Jawa Barat          |     
| 13000000   | Jawa Timur          |    
| 14000000   | Sumatera Utara      |   
| 15000000   | DKI Jakarta         |   
|  ...       |  ...                |   
| 41000000   | Di Yogyakarta       |  
| 42140000   | Kota Singkawang     | 
| 58300000   | Kota Depok          | 
| 12100000   | Bandung             | 
| 50200000   | Kabupaten Sukoharjo | 
| 41010000   | Kabupaten Sleman    | 
| 15310000   | Cilandak            | 
| 42140400   | Singkawang Barat    | 
| 41011200   | Mlati               | 
| 12110000   | Arjasari            | 
| 15310003   | Gandaria Selatan    | 
| 41011202   | Sinduadi            |   
+------------+---------------------+
```

I want to select the user in table user_base_info which has state = 90 in table borrow_progress and change the live_province, live_city, live_area_big, live_area_small code with name in table area.

I want the result looks like this:

```
+-------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|user_id| real_name |    live_province |   live_city      | live_area_big    | live_area_small  |
+-------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|331508 |  Donald   |   Di Yogyakarta  | Kabupaten Sleman |    Mlati         |    Sinduadi      |
+-------+-----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I have tried

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    borrow_progress a
        INNER JOIN
    user_base_info b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
        INNER JOIN
    area c ON c.code = b.live_city
WHERE
    state = 90
```

But this is not what I want.

Comment: When you say "not what I want", what specifically is wrong with it? It doesn't have the right selection of columns? It needs more joins against the area table to look up the other live_* codes? Something else?

Comment: @Rup I am a newbie so that is why I ask here to find if someone can fix my query

Comment: @Rup 1. I am a newbie so that is why I ask here to find if someone can fix my query.
2. When I did the 1st join, I count all the rows = 12173. After 2nd join it is = 12166. What in the world happen?

Comment: We don't have your data so we can't know for sure why you have that many rows, but it is the 'where' clause that filters down the number - how many rows do you get from `select * from borrow_progress where state = 90` ? - and after that you'd expect the number of rows to stay the same providing there is exactly one row per user_id in user_base_info and exactly one row per code in area. If there are multiple rows per ID in the join tables then the number will go up. If there are missing rows then the number will go down.

Comment: @ebuzz168 Why are you suprised? That the number decresed?

Comment: Another requirement to think about: what if one user has two loans in state 90? Do you want to output one row for them or two?

Comment: @Rup all of them. Two rows

Comment: @VBoka Yes, sir >.<

Comment: @ebuzz168 the number descresed because not all user_id's from one table have a matching record in another table and the same thing with third table. You have joined this three tables with a specific condition. And if this condition is not true then the rows will not show. Hope this explanation will help you understand better. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must join 4 copies of the table `area` to the other 2 tables. 
Each copy of `area` will return the name for each of the 4  columns: `live_province`, `live_city`, `live_area_big` and `live_area_small`:

```
select u.user_id, u.real_name,
  a1.name live_province,
  a2.name live_city,
  a3.name live_area_big,
  a4.name live_area_small
from user_base_info u
inner join borrow_progress b on b.user_id= u.user_id
inner join area a1 on a1.code = u.live_province
inner join area a2 on a2.code = u.live_city
inner join area a3 on a3.code = u.live_area_big
inner join area a4 on a4.code = u.live_area_small
where b.state = 90
```

If there is a case that the columns `live_province`, `live_city`, `live_area_big` and `live_area_small` in the table `user_base_info` to be `null` then use `left` joins instead of `inner` joins.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ubYq4bZb2u7nJqZzmLULdm/0).
Results:

```
| user_id | real_name | live_province | live_city        | live_area_big | live_area_small |
| ------- | --------- | ------------- | ---------------- | ------------- | --------------- |
| 331508  | Donald    | Di Yogyakarta | Kabupaten Sleman | Mlati         | Sinduadi        |
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. This is beyond my skill. I learn so much here

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    b.user_id
    , b.real_name
    , (select c1.name from area c1 where code = a.live_province) "live_province"
    , live_city      
    , (select c2.name from area c2 where code = a.live_area_big) "live_area_big"
    , (select c3.name from area c3 where code = a.live_area_big) "live_area_small"  
FROM borrow_progress a 
INNER JOIN user_base_info b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
INNER JOIN area c ON c.code = b.live_city
WHERE state = 90
```